# Erro ao conectar banco ORACLE com PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, oracle

Ao tentar me conectar a um banco de dados Oracle ORACLE aparece o seguinte erro:

> TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

Já configurei o php.ini e incluí as seguintes linhas:

```
extension=php_oci8.dll
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
extension=php_oracle.dll
```

Obs.: Meu arquivo de conexão está da seguinte forma:

`$conexao = oci_connect('usuario', 'senha', 'nome_do_banco');`

Comment: Possível solução para seu problema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345605/php-oci-connect-tnscould-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-ora-12154. Especificação para SERVICE_NAME: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams217.htm
Manual oci_connect: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.oci-connect.php

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu pesquisei, você precisa configurar a referência ao servidor Oracle na máquina cliente, no arquivo `tnsnames.ora`.

Um arquivo `.ora` teria uma sintaxe mais ou menos assim:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
    (SID_LIST =
        (SID_DESC =
            (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
            (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1)
            (PROGRAM = extproc)
        )
    )
LISTENER =
    (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
            (ADDRESS =
                (PROTOCOL = TCP)
                (HOST = MYSERVER)
                (PORT = 1521)
            )
        )
    )
```

Fonte: https://community.oracle.com/thread/367507

Answer (score -3):

tenta fazer isso no seu arquivo de `conexao.php`
eu uso desse jeito, pra conectar o *Oracle* com *PHP* é um pouco complicado.

```php
//Cria variavel de conexão

$vardb="(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST ={coloque o ip do host aqui})(PORT = {porta}))
(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = {nome configurado no tnsnames})))";

//Criar a conexao ORACLE

if(!@($conn_ora = oci_connect('login','senha',$var,'AL32UTF8'))){
    echo "Conexão falhou!"; 
} else { 
    //echo "Conexão OK!";   
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).